# Bootstrap datetimepicker is not working and error in console is showing $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker but its not working can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong.

Links which I have given are

```
     <script  src="{{ asset ('css/sidebar/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script  src="{{ asset ('css/sidebar/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript" ></script>
 <script src="{{asset('css/sidebar/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

```
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <script src="{{asset('css/sidebar/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
  <!-- daterangepicker -->
  <script src="{{asset('css/sidebar/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js')}}"></script>
      <!-- datepicker -->
     <script src="{{asset('css/sidebar/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{asset('css/sidebar/dist/js/demo.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('css/sidebar/bower_components/bootstrap-datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js')}}"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/sidebar/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css')}}">
   <!-- Daterange picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="
    {{asset('css/sidebar/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css')}}">
  <link href="{{asset('css/sidebar/bower_components/bootstrap-datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

And Code which i am using for text field is

```
      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Birthday</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="DOB">
                                <input type="text" value="{{ old('birthdate') }}" name="dateOfBirth" class="form-control pull-right" id="dateOfBirth" required>
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
                            </div>
                             @if ($errors->has('dateOfBirth'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('dateOfBirth') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Script is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$("#DOB").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'});
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`$ is not defined` occurs when you are using jquery code without loading it first.

As you can see in your sequence:

```
<script  src="{{ asset ('css/sidebar/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script  src="{{ asset ('css/sidebar/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript" ></script>
 <script src="{{asset('css/sidebar/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

You are loading jquery in the end. You are loading two dependent javascripts of jquery before jquery is even loaded.

You should load jquery first, and then other dependencies.

```
<script src="{{asset('css/sidebar/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>`
<script  src="{{ asset ('css/sidebar/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script  src="{{ asset ('css/sidebar/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Also make sure your script is in the end: (and make sure jquery and datetimepicker are loaded before this)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#DOB").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'});
</script>
```

Comment: I have done these changings still its giving the same error

Comment: Could you tell me where is your script located? It should be on the bottom of the page. @NidaAkram

Comment: yup its at the bottom of my page

Comment: Try putting your code inside `$(document).ready(function() {   YOUR_CODE_HERE  });`

Comment: done this but still i am not shown with the calendar

Answer (score 0):

You have little things wrong...
the loading order of your JS

```
<script  src="{{ asset ('css/sidebar/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script  src="{{ asset ('css/sidebar/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="{{asset('css/sidebar/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

right is

```
<script src="{{asset('css/sidebar/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script  src="{{ asset ('css/sidebar/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript" ></script>`
<script  src="{{ asset ('css/sidebar/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

And then you have to do wait until page (DOM render) is still ready.
This looks like:

```
$(function() {
$("#DOB").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call jquery reference file on top and all other plugin files then after this.

Change the order of files reference.

Comment: I have changed the files reference but still its giving the same error

Comment: You are calling $ sign before the scripts tag in html directly remove those lines or logic

Comment: Sorry I couldnot i understand

Comment: I have added my script tag after the refernces error is removed but the calendar is not opening in my text field what will be the problem with that

Comment: Remove if condition you have in your html

Comment: done this but still i am not shown with the calendar

Comment: Is $ issue resolved if so then I guide you for how to show datetimepicker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156148/discussion-between-nida-akram-and-qaiser-mehmood).